# Facebook Comments Plugin - Message Failure

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I'm testing a Facebook Comments Plugin on a website I'm developping.

For some reason, when I try to comment in it to test the plugin, I receive the message 'Échec du message', which is french for basically 'Message failure'.

No errors are thrown in the dialog box or in the console.

[image]

What could trigger this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that facebook has a few URLs that cannot be used as a reffering url for the comment plugin.

Seems hyperurl.co doesn't work, but smarturl.it does.